# How can I use Skype with lxc?

Tags: security, skype, container, jails, lxc

Under Scientific-linux?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC

I just want to separate Skype, because I don't trust it. We are using it only to call/chat with people, no file transfers!

Comment: I did that in the past for several applications (Dropbox, Eclipse, TeamViewer), but it's always a lot of try&error because you need to map x11, sound etc to your container and often 3rd party developers forget to add all dependencies to their products; they normally only test in fully working systems instead of chroot/containers. Dropbox finally worked, TeamViewer didn't. Unfortunately, I never tried skype and don't know if I find the time this weekend.

Answer (score 3):

[Firejail](http://l3net.wordpress.com/projects/firejail/) is a Linux namespaces sandbox program that can jail Skype, Firefox or any other GUI software. It should work on any Linux computer.

Answer (score 1):

There're builtin application restriction approaches, you don't have to run it within a container.

Take a look at [apparmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor), it should fit all your needs. e.g what file it can read / write, what binaries it can execute